# Can you please fix the mistakes in translating these prayers from Koine Greek to English (Part 1 of 2)?

Tags: greek, translation-check, greek-to-english-translation

This question is continued [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7665/can-you-please-fix-the-mistakes-in-translating-these-prayers-from-koine-greek-to)

I do not know nearly enough Koine Greek to point out what I am specifically unsure about. That said, I do know enough to see that the Greek and English texts do not quite line up in places.

Some background: These are 1 through 12 of 24 prayers that were written in the 12th century by St. Nercess the Graceful in Classical Armenian. Sometime shortly later, they were translated into Koine Greek. Clearly the Koine Greek text is somewhat different from the Classical Armenian text on which the English translation is based though. So I am looking for the English text to be edited to match the Koine Greek text.

Πιστεύω καὶ ὀμολογῶ καὶ προσκυνῶ σοι Πάτερ, Υἰέ καὶ Θεῖον Πνεῦμα, ἄκτιστος καὶ ἀθάνατος φύσις, ἠ πλάσασα Ἀγγέλους τε καὶ ἀνθρώπους καὶ ποιήσασα τὰ πάντα. Ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου.

I confess with faith and worship you, Father, Son and Holy Spirit, uncreated and immortal Essence, creator of angels, humans and of all that exists. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

Πιστεύω καὶ ὁμολογῶ καὶ προσκυνῶ σοι ἀδιαίρετον φῶς, Ἁγία Τριάς, εἷς Θεός ὁ ποιήσας τὸ φῶς καὶ διώξας τὸ σκότος, φώτισον τὴν ταπεινήν μου ψυχήν, καὶ ἀποσκέδασον τῆς ἀγνοίας τὸ σκότος καὶ τῶν ἁμαρτιῶν, καὶ νῦν μέ ἐν τῇ ὤρᾳ ταύτῃ τὴν τῆς αὐγῆς σου ἀκτῖνα τῷ τῆς διανοίας μου γνόφῳ ἐγχέων, αξίωσον, ἵνα ἀρεστάς σοι εὔξωμαι προσευχάς, δέξαι οὖν, φιλάνθρωπε, τὰς δεήσες τοῦ δούλου οου. Καὶ ἐλέησον με τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

I confess with faith and worship you, O Indivisible Light, unified Holy Trinity and one Godhead; creator of light and dispeller of darkness, dispel from my soul the darkness of sin and ignorance, and enlighten my mind at this moment, so that I may pray to you according to your will, and receive from you the fulfillment of my requests. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

Ἐπουράνιε Θεέ, Πάτερ παντοκράτωρ, ό πέμψας τὸν ἀγαπητόν σου Υἱόν, ἵνα τὸ πλανηθέν πρόβατον ἀναλάβῃ τοῖς ὤμοις εὔρών, ἥμαρτον εἰς τὸν οὐρανόν καὶ ἐνώπιόν σου, δέξαι με, Πάτερ, ὡς τὸν ἄσωτον Υἱόν, ἀξίωσον με τῆς πρώτης στολῆς, ἧς ἐστερήθην διὰ τῆς ἁμαρτίας. Καὶ ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου, καὶ ἐμὲ τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

Heavenly Father, true God, who sent your beloved Son to seek the lost sheep. I have sinned against heaven and before you; receive me as the prodigal son, and clothe me with my former garment, of which I was deprived by sin. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

Υἱὲ καὶ Λόγε τοῦ Θεοῦ, Θεὸς ἀληθής, ό ἐκ τῶν Πατρικῶν κόλπων κατελθών διὰ τήν ἡμετέραν σωτηρίαν, ό σαρκωθείς ἐκ Πνεύματος Ἁγίου καὶ Μαρίας τῆς Παρθένου καὶ ἐνανθρωπήσας, σταυρωθείς τε καὶ παθών, ταφεὶς δε καὶ ἀναστάς ἐκ νεκρῶν τῇ τρίτῃ ἡμέρα, ἀνελθών τε εἰς τοὺς οὐρανούς, ἥμαρτον εἰς τὸν οὐρανόν καὶ ἐνώπιον σου, μνήσθητί μου ὥς τοῦ ληστοῦ, ὅταν ἔλθης ἐν τῇ Βασιλείᾳ σου. Καὶ ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου, καὶ ἐμὲ τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

Son of God, true God, who descended from the bosom of the Father, and took on flesh from the holy Virgin Mary for our salvation; crucified, buried, and raised from the dead, ascended in glory to the Father; I have sinned against heaven and before you; remember me like the penitent thief when you come into your kingdom. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

Πνεῦμα Ἄγιον, Θεὸς ἀληθής, τό καταβάν εἰς τὸν Ιορδάνην καὶ εἰς τὸ Ὑπερῷον, τό φωτίσαν μέ τῷ λουτρῷ τοῦ Βαπτίσματος, ἥμαρτον εἰς τὸν οὐρανόν καὶ ἐνώπιον σου, καθάρισον με πάλιν τῷ πυρί σου τῷ Θείῳ, ὡς ἐν πύριναις γλώσσαις τοὺς Ἀποστόλους ἐκαθάρισάς ποτε. Καὶ ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου, καὶ ἐμὲ τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

Spirit of God, true God, who descended on the river Jordan, and into the Upper Room; who enlightened me by the baptism of the Holy Font, I have sinned against heaven and before you. Purify me again with your divine fire, as the fiery tongues purified the Holy Apostles. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

Ἥμαρτον ἐνώπιον σου, ἅκτιστέ Φύσις, λόγῳ, ἔργῳ καὶ διανοίᾳ, μὴ μνησθῇς Κύριε, διὰ τὸ Ὄνομά σου τὸ Ἅγιον τῶν προτέρων μου παραπτωμάτων. Καὶ ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου, καὶ ἐμὲ τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

Uncreated Essence, I have sinned against you, with my mind, with my soul and with my body, remember not my former sins for the sake of your Holy Name. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

Ὁ πανταχοῦ παρὼν καὶ τὰ πάντα θεωρῶν, Κύριε, ἐνώπιόν σου ἥμαρτον λόγῳ, ἔργῳ καὶ διανοίᾳ, ἐξάλειψον τῶν ἀμαρτιῶν μου τὸ χειρόγραφον, καὶ γράψον τὸ ὄνομά μου ἐν τῷ βιβλίῳ τής ζωῆς. Καὶ ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου, καὶ ἐμὲ τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

Beholder of all, I have sinned against you, in thought, word and deed; erase the record of my transgressions, and write my name in the book of Life. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

Ὁ ἐξετάζων καρδίας καὶ νεφρούς, Κύριε, ἥμαρτον εἰς σὲ ἐκουσίως καὶ ἀκουσίως, εἰδώς τε καὶ μὴ εἰδώς, δὸς μοι τῷ ἀθλίῳ τῶν ἁμαρτιῶν μου τὴν ἄφεσιν, καὶ γάρ ἐξ οὗ τοῦ λουτροῦ τὴς παλιγγενεσίας τετύχηκα μέχρι τοῦ νῦν, πᾶν κακόν ἔπραξα, πᾶσαν ἁμαρτίαν ἐποίησα, πᾶσάν μου αἴσθησιν καὶ πᾶν μέλος μιάνας. Καὶ ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου, καὶ ἐμὲ τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

O Searcher of secrets, I have sinned against you, willingly and inadvertently, knowingly and unknowingly. Grant forgiveness unto me a sinner; since from my birth through the holy baptism, until this day, I have sinned before you Lord, with all my senses and in all the members of my body. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

Ὁ μόνος καθαρός καὶ ἀκήρατος Κύριος, θοῦ φυλακήν τοῖς ὀφθαλμοῖς μου τὸν φόβον σου τὸν ἅγιον, εἰς ἀποτροπήν πάσης ἀπρεποῦς θέας καὶ περιέργου καὶ ἀχαλινώτου ὁράσεως, τοῖς ὠσί μου, μὴ ἀκούειν λόγου πονηροῦ καὶ ἀκάθαρτου, τῷ στόματί μου καὶ τῇ γλώττῃ μου, εἰς τὸ μὴ ψεύδεσθαι, τῇ καρδίᾳ μου, εἰς τὸ μὴ διανοεῖσθαι κακόν, ταῖς χερσί μου, μὴ ἀδικεῖν ἀδικίαν, καὶ τοῖς ποσί μου, μὴ ὁδεύειν ὁδόν ἄδικον, ἀλλ’ εἴθυνον τὰ διαβήματά μου, ἵνα ποιῶ τὰ προστάγματά σου. Καὶ ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου, καὶ ἐμὲ τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

All-provident Lord, place your holy awe as a guardian before my eyes, so that I may not look with askance; before my ears, not to delight in hearing evil discourses, before my mouth, not to speak falsehood, before my heart, not to mediate wickedness, before my hands, not to commit injustice, before my feet, not to walk on the paths of iniquity; rather, guide always my motions, that they may be according to all your commandments. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

Κύριε Ἰησοῦ Χριστέ, ζῶν πῦρ, ἄναψον κἀμοὶ ἐν τῇ καρδίᾳ μου τὸ πῦρ τῆς Θείας σου ἀγάπης, ἵνα καθαρίσῃ τήν εῤῤυπωμένην μου ψυχήν, ἵνα εξαλείψῃ τοῦ σώματος μου τὰ ἁμαρτήματα, ἵνα ἅψῃ ἐν τῇ καρδίᾳ μου τὸ φῶς τῆς σῆς ἐλλάμψεως. Καὶ ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου, καὶ ἐμὲ τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

O Christ, the quickening fire, inflame my soul with the fire of your love that you dispersed over the earth, so that it may consume the stains of my soul; cleanse my conscience and my mind, purify my body from sin, and kindle the light of your knowledge in my heart. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

Κύριε Ἰησοῦ Χριστέ, ἡ Σοφία τοῦ Πατρός, δὸς μοι τήν σοφίαν τοῦ φρονεῖν λαλεῖν τε καὶ ποιεῖν πὰ ἀγαθά ἐνῶπιόν σου διὰ παντός, ῥῦσαί με τῶν παραπτωμάτων, ἔργου, λόγου, ἤ διανοίας. Καὶ ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου, καὶ ἐμὲ τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

O Jesus, wisdom of the Father, grant me the wisdom that I may always think, speak, and do what is good in your sight. deliver me from evil thoughts, words and deeds. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

Ἀγαθοδέκτα Κύριε, ὁ τέλειῶν τήν πάντων βουλὴν, μὴ με παραιτήσῃς βαδίζειν κατ’ ἐμὴν ἐπιθυμίαν, ἀλλ’ όδήγησον κατὰ τὸ σόν θέλημα τὸ ἅγιον. Καὶ ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου, καὶ ἐμὲ τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

Benevolent Lord, your will encompasses all that is good, you are the director of the will. Do not let me follow the inclinations of my heart; rather, guide me to always walk according to your good pleasure. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

Comment: Hi and welcome!  It may be helpful to review our guidelines for translation – [How can I ask a translation or homework question?](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/a/144/12).  In particular, can you show the results of your efforts to translate these texts?  It's best to focus your questions on specific difficult elements in the translation, rather than make a large, generic request like this.

Comment: @Nathaniel: I just edited my question. Is this better?

Comment: Much better! Though your question is still *enormous*, and it might be better to break it down into sections.

Comment: Also where did these prayers come from?

Comment: I agree with @Draconis: This question is too long. I recommend taking just one paragraph/section (the one you have most doubts about) and leaving the rest out. You can then ask about them in separate questions, but it's better to wait for feedback about one part before asking about others. That way you can learn more on the way!

Comment: @Draconis: These prayers were written in the 12th century by St. Nercess the Graceful in Classical Armenian. Sometime shortly later, they were translated into Koine Greek. Clearly the Koine Greek text is somewhat different from the Classical Armenian text on which the English translation is based though. So I was looking for an English translation of the Koine Greek version.

Comment: @Joonas Ilmavirta: Would you rather I ask 24 separate questions? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Interesting, so your goal is to compare the Koine Greek against the Armenian-to-English version? I'd been thinking the English was your translation, but it doesn't quite line up in places.

Comment: @Draconis: Yes, my goal is to get a Koine-Greek-to-English version and compare it to the Armenian-to-English version.

Comment: @7MessRobHackOpen Yes, that's what I'm saying. But I wouldn't ask them at the same time. Instead, start by asking one or maybe two of those smaller questions. Feedback from the first question(s) will be useful for the rest of the text, and you can ask new questions using newfound knowledge.

Comment: As Nathaniel (and the link he gives) suggests, it's good to explain what you are unsure about. Giving a chunk of text and saying "please give feedback" is a little too open-ended. That can be part of the question, but if you are unsure about something specific, please elaborate on that.

Comment: @Joonas Ilmavirta: Here is the problem - I don't know nearly enough Koine Greek to point out what I am specifically unsure about. That said, I do know enough to see that, as Draconis pointed out, "it doesn't quite line up in places." Does that make sense?

Comment: @7MessRobHackOpen It makes sense. Whatever the situation is, it's best to describe it in the question. As your question is currently written, there's not enough context and the origin of the English and Greek texts is unclear. The background can be anything, but disclosing it helps a lot. For example, we get questions where people have tried Google Translate and ask us to check if the translation makes sense. Anyway, taking a smaller chunk makes people much more likely to actually read the text, so start small. Answering the question as it is now is a lot of work.

Comment: @Joonas Ilmavirta: I just edited the question again. I just want to give people a chance to see if they will answer the question as it is right now. If they do not, then I will try what you are suggesting (taking a smaller chunk)

Comment: I was wondering why Armenia was mentioned in the text. It is in the last prayer, the doxology. If you want to start 'small,' section 4 and the last one  are the only sections where I've noticed significant variants.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fourth one:

> Υἱὲ καὶ Λόγε τοῦ Θεοῦ, Θεὸς ἀληθής, ό ἐκ τῶν Πατρικῶν κόλπων κατελθών διὰ τήν ἡμετέραν σωτηρίαν, ό σαρκωθείς ἐκ Πνεύματος Ἁγίου καὶ Μαρίας τῆς Παρθένου καὶ ἐνανθρωπήσας, σταυρωθείς τε καὶ παθών, ταφεὶς δε καὶ ἀναστάς ἐκ νεκρῶν τῇ τρίτῃ ἡμέρα, ἀνελθών τε εἰς τοὺς οὐρανούς, ἥμαρτον εἰς τὸν οὐρανόν καὶ ἐνώπιον σου, μνήσθητί μου ὥς τοῦ ληστοῦ, ὅταν ἔλθης ἐν τῇ Βασιλείᾳ σου. Καὶ ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου, καὶ ἐμὲ τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

From Greek:

> Son and Word of God, true God, who came down from the bosom of the Father to be our Savior, who took on flesh from the Holy Spirit and the Virgin Mary and became human, who was crucified, who suffered, who was buried and rose up from the dead after three days, then ascended to Heaven: I have sinned toward Heaven and toward you, face to face. Remember me like the pirate, when you go to Your Kingdom. And have mercy on your creatures, and me, who has sinned excessively against you.

From Armenian, to compare:

> Son of God, true God, who descended from the bosom of the Father, and took on flesh from the holy Virgin Mary for our salvation; crucified, buried, and raised from the dead, ascended in glory to the Father; I have sinned against heaven and before you; remember me like the penitent thief when you come into your kingdom. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

(Warning, my translation is more literal than poetic, and Koine isn't my specialty, so some parts might be wrong. But I tried to keep the exact meaning as closely as possible rather than making the prayer sound good in English.)

Comment: This looks very good to me. A couple of minor points: κτίσματα here is "creatures", and I'd take τὸν ἡμαρτηκότα σοι as "the one who has sinned against you" (rather than a dative of possession as your translation implies).

Comment: @TKR Thanks! Both of those make much more sense, and I edited them in.