# Can you please fix the mistakes in translating these prayers from Koine Greek to English (Part 2 of 2)?

Tags: greek, translation-check, greek-to-english-translation

This is a continuation from [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7664/can-you-please-fix-the-mistakes-in-translating-these-prayers-from-koine-greek-to)

I do not know nearly enough Koine Greek to point out what I am specifically unsure about. That said, I do know enough to see that the Greek and English texts do not quite line up in places.

Some background: These are 9 through 16 of 24 prayers that were written in the 12th century by St. Nercess the Graceful in Classical Armenian. Sometime shortly later, they were translated into Koine Greek. Clearly the Koine Greek text is somewhat different from the Classical Armenian text on which the English translation is based though. So I am looking for the English text to be edited to match the Koine Greek text.

Ἐπουράνιε Βασιλεῦ, ἀξίωσόν με τῆς σῆς Βασιλείας, ἥν ὑπέσχου τοῖς ἐκλεκτοῖς, δὸς ἰσχύν τῇ καρδίᾳ μου διὰ μίσους ἔχειν τὰ ἁμαρτήματα, καὶ μόνον σέ φιλεῖν, ποιεῖν τε τὸ σὸν θέλημα. Καὶ ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου, καὶ ἐμὲ τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

Heavenly King, grant me your kingdom which was promised to your beloved, and strengthen my heart to hate sin, and to love only you, and to do your will. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

Φύλαξόν μου Κύριε τήν ψυχήν καὶ τὸ σῶμα, τοῦ ζωοποιοῦ σου Σταυροῦ τῷ σημείῳ, ἐκ τής ἀπάτης τῶν ἁμαρτιῶν, καὶ πονηρῶν πειρασμῶν, ἐξ ἀνθρώπου ἀδίκου, καὶ παντός κινδύνου ψυχῆς τε καὶ σώματος. Καὶ ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου, καὶ ἐμὲ τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

Upholder of all creatures, preserve by the sign of your cross, my soul and body, from the allurements of sin, from the temptation of evil, from unjust people, and from all dangers physical and spiritual. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

Ἠ δεξιά σου, Χριστέ, ἐπισκιασάτω μοι ἡμέρας καὶ νυκτός ἐν τῷ οἰκουρεῖν με, ὁδοιπορεῖν, καθεύδειν, τε, καὶ ἐν τῷ ἀγρυπνεῖν, ἵνα μὴ κλονηθῶ. Καὶ ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου, καὶ ἐμὲ τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

O Christ, guardian of all, may your right hand guard and shelter me, day and night; while at home and while traveling; while I am sleeping and while I am awake, so that I may never falter. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

Κύριε καὶ Θεέ μου, ὁ ἀνοίγων τήν χεῖρα σου καὶ ἐμπληρῶν τὰ σύμπαντα χρηστότητος, εἰς χεῖρας σου παρατίθημι τὴν ψυχήν μου, Σὺ παρασκεύασον αὐτῇ πᾶν ἀγαθόν νῦν τε καὶ ἐν τῷ μέλλοντι αἰῶνι. Καὶ ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου, καὶ ἐμὲ τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

My God, inside your open hand the whole creation is filled with your bounty. Unto you I commit my being; take care of me and provide the needful for my soul and body, from this time forth for evermore. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

Ὁ τοὺς πεπλανημένους ἀναστρέφων, Κύριε, ἀνάστρεψον κἀμὲ ἐκ φαύλης εἰς καλὴν συνήθειαν, καὶ διατύπωσον ἐν τῇ καρδίᾳ μου τὴν φρικτήν ἡμέραν τοῦ θανάτου, καὶ τὸν φόβον τής γεέννης, καὶ τῆς σῆς Βασιλείας τὸν ἔρωτα, ἵνα μετανοήσας πράξω τί ἀγαθόν. Καὶ ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου, καὶ ἐμὲ τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

Finder of the lost, turn me away from my evil habits to good ones; and imprint on my soul the dreadful day of death, the fear of eternal punishment, and the love of your kingdom, so that I may repent of my sins, and I may follow the path of righteousness. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner

Ὤ πηγή τῆς ἀθανασίας, ἄντλησον ἐκ τὴς καρδίας μου, ὡς ἐκ τῆς μοιχαλίδος ποτὲ, δάκρυα μετανοίας, ἵνα λούσω τὰ ἁμαρτήματά μου πρὶν ἄν ἐκ τοῦ κόσμου ἐξέλθω. Καὶ ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου, καὶ ἐμὲ τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

Fountain of immortality, cause the tears of repentance to flow from my heart, like those of Mary Magdalene, so that, before I depart this world, I may wash away the sins of my soul. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

Οἰκτίρμων καὶ πολυεύσπλαγχνε Κύριε, ἀξίωσὸν με ἀκατακρίτως σοι προσελθεῖν, τῇ Μεταλήψει τῶν θείων καὶ ἐνδόξων καὶ ἀχράντων καὶ ζωοποιῶν σου Μυστηρίων τοῦ ἁγίου σου σώματος καὶ τοῦ τιμίου σου αἵματος. Καὶ ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου, καὶ ἐμὲ τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

Grantor of mercy, grant that I may come to you with true faith, with good works, and the communion of your Holy Body and Blood. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

Ὁ μόνος ἀγαθός Κύριος, Ἀγγέλου με ἀγαθοῦ ἀξίωσον, ὅπως τὴν ψυχὴν μου λάβῃ μειδιῶντι προσώπῳ, ἡνίκα μέλλω ἀπαίρειν τῆς γῆς, καὶ φυγαδεύσῃ προθύμως τοὺς ζητοῦντας με συλλαβεῖν πικρούς ἐχθρούς. Καὶ ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου, καὶ ἐμὲ τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

Benevolent Lord, commit me to a good angel, who may deliver up my soul in peace, and convey it undisturbed through the malice of evil, to heavenly places. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

Χριστέ τὸ φῶς τὸ ἀληθινόν, τὴν ψυχὴν μου ἀξίωσον, ἵνα ὄψηται ἐν τῇ ἡμέρᾳ τῆς κλήσεως, τῆς δόξης σου τὸ ἀπρόσιτον φῶς, καὶ ἀνάπαυσον αὐτὴν ἐν δικαίων σκηναῖς τῇ ἐλπίδι τῶν ἀγαθῶν μέχρι τῆς φρικτής ἡμέρας τῆς Παρουσίας σου. Καὶ ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου, καὶ ἐμὲ τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

O Christ, the true Light, make my soul worthy to encounter with joy the light of your divine glory, on the day I will be called by you; and to rest in good hope, in the mansions of the righteous, until the great day of your coming. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

Ω δικαστὰ Χριστὲ, ὅταν ἔλθης μετὰ δόξης τοῦ Πατρὸς κρῖναι ζώντας καὶ νεκροὺς, μὴ εἰσέλθης εἰς κρίσιν μετά τοῦ δούλου σου, ἀλλά ῥῦσαι με τοῦ αἰωνίου πυρός, ἀκούσω δέ τὴς πρός τοὺς δικαίους μακαρίας κλήσεως ἐν τῇ Βασιλείᾳ τῶν οὐρανῶν. Καὶ ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου, καὶ ἐμὲ τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

Righteous judge, when you come with the glory of the Father to judge the living and the dead, do not enter into judgement with your servant; but save me from the eternal fire, and make me worthy to hear the most blessed call of the righteous for those who will enter to your heavenly kingdom. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

Φιλάνθρωπε Κύριε, ἐλέησον πάντας τοὺς πιστεύοντάς εἰς σὲ, τοὺς μισοῦντας καὶ ἀγαπῶντας με, οἰκείους, καὶ ἀλλοτρίους, ζῶντας καὶ νεκροὺς, χάρισαι τοῖς ἐχθροῖς μου καὶ τοῖς διώκουσι με ἄφεσιν τῶν ἑαυτῶν ἁμαρτιῶν, καὶ ἐπίστρεψον αὐτούς ἀπὸ πάντων τῶν κακῶν, ὧν εἰς ἐμὲ ἐβουλεύσαντο, ἵνα κὰυτοι ἄξιοι γένωνται τοῦ ἐλέους σου. Καὶ ἐλέησον τὰ κτίσματά σου, καὶ ἐμὲ τὸν ὑπερβαλλόντως ἡμαρτηκότα σοι.

All-merciful Lord, have mercy on all those who believe in you; on my beloved ones, and on those who are strangers to me; on all those I know, and on those unknown to me; on the living and on the dead; even forgive my enemies, and those who hate me, forgive the trespasses they have committed against me; and relieve them from the malice they bear towards me, so that they become worthy of your mercy. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me, a manifold sinner.

Πρόσδεξαι Κύριε, τὰς δεήσεις τοῦ δούλου σου, καὶ ἐπάκουσον μου τοῦ σοῦ ἱκέτου, Πρεσβείαις τῆς παναχράντου δεσποίνης ἡμῶν Θεοτόκου καὶ Ἀειπαρθένου Μαρίας, τοῦ τιμίου ἐνδόξου προφήτου προδρόμου καὶ Βαπτιστοῦ Ἰωάννου, τοῦ Ἁγίου πρωτομάρτυρος καὶ ἀρχιδιακόνου Στεφάνου, τοῦ ἐν Ἁγίοις Πατρὸς ἡμῶν Γρηγορίου Πατριάρχου τής Μεγάλης Ἀρμενίας, τοῦ φωτίσαντος ἡμᾶς, τῶν Ἁγιων ἐνδόξων καὶ πανευφήμων Ἀποστόλων, Προφητών, Διδασκάλων, Μαρτύρων, Πατριαρχών, Ἀναχωρητών, Παρθένων, καὶ πάντων τῶν Ἁγίων τῶν ἐν οὐρανῷ καὶ ἐν γῇ. Σοί γὰρ πρέπει πᾶσα δόξα, τιμὴ, καὶ προσκύνησις σὺν τῷ ἀνάρχῳ σου Πατρὶ καὶ τῷ παναγίῳ καὶ ἀγαθῷ καὶ ζωοποιῷ σου Πνεύματι, νῦν καὶ ἀεί καὶ εἰς τοὺς αἰῶνας τῶν αἰῶνων. Ἀμήν.

O glorious Lord, receive the prayers of your servant; and fulfill my requests that are deemed good. Through the intercession of the Holy Mother of God, and St. John the Baptist, and St. Stephen the first martyr, and St. Gregory our Illuminator, and the Holy Apostles, Prophets, Doctors of the Church, Martyrs, Patriarchs, Hermits, Virgins, and all your saints in heaven and on earth. Unto you, O indivisible Holy Trinity, be glory and worship, forever and ever. Amen.

Comment: 3 sections done. I don't have time for more.Good wishes.

Answer (score 1):

.9.

> The one pure and incorrupt Lord, place a guard to my eyes, your holy Fear, for the turning away of every indecent sight and of unbridled and inquisitive looking; [place a guard, your Fear] to my ears so as not to hear wicked and foul talk; before my throat and my tongue not to speak falsehood;  before my heart, not to devise wickedness; before my hands, not to commit injustice; before my feet, not to walk in the path of iniquity; rather, guide always my steps, that I do your commands. Have mercy upon your creatures, and on me a manifold sinner.

**.19.**

> Lord, lover of mankind, have mercy on all who trust in you, on those who hate and those who love me, on family and strangers, living and dead, show kindness to my enemies and to those who prosecute *(legal term)* me, take away their own sins and turn them away from all the evils which they counselled against me, so that they themselves may be worthy of your forgiveness. And have mercy on your creatures, and on me, who’ve excessively failed you.

.24.

> Πρόσδεξαι Κύριε, τὰς δεήσεις τοῦ δούλου σου, καὶ ἐπάκουσον μου τοῦ σοῦ ἱκέτου,

Receive, Lord, the prayers of your servant, and hearken unto me your suppliant,

> Πρεσβείαις τῆς παναχράντου δεσποίνης ἡμῶν Θεοτόκου καὶ Ἀειπαρθένου
>   Μαρίας,

by the Gifts-of-Honour of our sinless Lady Mother of God and Ever-Virgin Mary,

> τοῦ τιμίου ἐνδόξου προφήτου προδρόμου καὶ Βαπτιστοῦ Ἰωάννου,

of the prophet worthy of honour, Forerunner and Baptist John,

> τοῦ Ἁγίου πρωτομάρτυρος καὶ ἀρχιδιακόνου Στεφάνου,

of the holy Protomartyr and Archdeacon Stephen,

> τοῦ ἐν Ἁγίοις Πατρὸς ἡμῶν Γρηγορίου Πατριάρχου τής Μεγάλης Ἀρμενίας,
>   τοῦ φωτίσαντος ἡμᾶς,

and of our Father among the Saints, Gregory Patriarch of Great Armenia, who enlightened us,

> τῶν Ἁγιων ἐνδόξων καὶ πανευφήμων Ἀποστόλων,

of the Holy, glorious, and triumphant Apostles,

> Προφητών, Διδασκάλων, Μαρτύρων, Πατριαρχών, Ἀναχωρητών, Παρθένων, καὶ πάντων τῶν Ἁγίων τῶν ἐν οὐρανῷ καὶ ἐν γῇ.

of Prophets, Teachers, Martyrs, Patriarchs, Anchorites, Virgins, and all your saints in heaven and on earth.

> Σοί γὰρ πρέπει πᾶσα δόξα, τιμὴ, καὶ προσκύνησις

For to you is due all glory, honour and worship,

> σὺν τῷ ἀνάρχῳ σου Πατρὶ καὶ τῷ παναγίῳ καὶ ἀγαθῷ καὶ ζωοποιῷ σου
>   Πνεύματι,

together with the Father supreme, and your all-holy and good life-giving Spirit,

> νῦν καὶ ἀεί καὶ εἰς τοὺς αἰῶνας τῶν αἰῶνων. Ἀμήν.

now and ever and to the ages of ages. Amen.

Comment: I just put the Greek back for 13 through 24. See 1 through 12 here: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7664/can-you-please-fix-the-mistakes-in-translating-these-prayers-from-koine-greek-to

Comment: I find Πρεσβείαις very interesting. It doesn't seem to say "by the intercession of Saints" 'my' petitions will be heard; rather, the Saints gifts of Praise and Honour carry 'my' requests. Is that in the Armenian?